# CSS in React makes all buttons disappear?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

The css for my button in NavBar is applied to every button, which it shouldn't. This results in the button called 'Search' (see picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxH3t.png)) which I actually want to stay visible, to disappear because NavBar.css has a media query in it. The NavBar.css is only for the NavBar.js, why it is causing the every button to disappear?

Picture of when window is large:
[image: When window size is large]
Picture of when window is small. The 'Search' button disappears which is not the intension.
[image: when window is small]

```
//App.js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import NavBar_ from './NavBar_';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <NavBar_ />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

---

```
//NavBar_.js
import React from 'react'
import Button from './Button'
import './NavBar_.css'

const NavBar_ = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button />
        </div>
    )
}
export default NavBar_
```

---

```
//Home.js
import React from 'react'
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div className='main-hero'>
            <div className='hero-bar'>
                <SearchBar />
            </div>


        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

---

```
//SearchBar.js
import React from 'react'

const SearchBar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <form>
                <input
                    className='search-bar'
                    id='search-location'
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Town'
                />
                <button className='submit-search' type='submit'>
                    Search
                </button>

            </form>

        </>
    )
}

export default SearchBar
```

---

```
//Button.js
import React from 'react'
import './Button.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Button = () => {
    return (
        <Link to="/sign-up">
            <button>Sign Up</button>
        </Link>
    )
};

export default Button;
```

---

```
//NavBar_.css
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    button {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: CSS is still CSS, even when you embed it in a react app.  Your CSS rule applies to all `button` elements.  If you don't want that, scope it to a specific button using a className.

Comment: So even though the NavBar.css is only used inside NavBar.js, its css will be applied globally if a global name is used in NavBar.css?

Comment: That is correct.  React does not scope CSS to the components that happen to contain the CSS rules.  If you define a global rule, it's gonna stay global.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader and/or https://www.npmjs.com/package/scoped-css-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS rules are global to the page they run on. This means the CSS you include with your `NavBar` will still be in scope and applied globally. The `NavBar.css` unconditionally applies the `display: none` rule to all buttons.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Use a `class` or `id` to restrict the scope of the rule. Example, only `button` elements with the `"signup"` class attribute.

[Class Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

NavBar_.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  button.navbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

NavBar_.js

```
const NavBar_ = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button className="navbar" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Button.css

```
button.signup {
  ... signup button rules ...
}
```

Button.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Button.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Button = () => {
  return (
    <Link to="/sign-up">
      <button className="signup">Sign Up</button>
    </Link>
  )
};
```

Comment: The "navbar" in NavBar_.css must be changed to "signup", else it won't work.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever Feel free to propose an edit to the code above for what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you style your components in React, actually it applies to every component you have. so you should use specific`class` or `id` for that special element, or use [CSS module](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) or [styled component](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) for styling.

I prefer `css module`. In this solution, you change `Button.css` to `Button.module.css` and import that to `Button.js`.

```
import classes from './Button.module.css'
```

In this way, you have a special style only for `Button.js`.